# Export/Serialzie Google chart options

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Is it possible to export/serialize Google Chart settings?

I wanna export my google chart and store it into DB.

Let me explain.
I am creating chart editor in which user can change some settings (title, colors etc.) For example, if user wants to change the title I use this `chart.m.title = 'My new title'`. And after user clicks on save button I want to serialize settings and store it in DB (API call to my backend - anyway that's not what I am asking.).

This is simple chart code from [Google Chart Documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
          ['2013',  1000,      400],
          ['2014',  1170,      460],
          ['2015',  660,       1120],
          ['2016',  1030,      540]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Year',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
          vAxis: {minValue: 0}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**I am looking for this kind of methods:**

```
// this values I will store in my database
// and it will help me create same chart in future
// with chart.draw(datasource, options);
var options = chart.options() 
var datasource = chart.datasource()
```

Comment: you want to use a [ChartWrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject), then you can use `toJSON()`...

Comment: Thanks that's what was I looking for.